# Should I refactor this to use a Map?

Tags: java, loops

I have a list of products, these can have different forms. I want to group several forms under the same group so that for example form1, form2 and form3 are now treated as group1. The way the input is configured to indicate a form should belong to a group is like so:

```
["form1,group1", "form2,group1", "form3,group1"]
```

To them separate the strings and replace the form I came up with the following code:

```
            if (!formAliasList.isEmpty() && !form.isEmpty()) {
                for(String alias: formAliasList) {
                    String[] splitted = alias.split(",",2);
                    if(splitted[0].trim().toLowerCase().contains(form.toLowerCase()))
                        form = splitted[1];
                }
            }
```

This is working just fine. But I feel this could perhaps be simplified into a map, if so show should I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know if factoring it into a map specifically is necessary, but I would put it into *some* form where you're not having to split and lowercase things repeatedly.

Comment: Do you mean to change the input into a map or use a map in your code sample?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and is more likely to get an answer on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with stream:

```
    String[] array = {"form1,group1", "form2,group1", "form4,group2", "form3,group1"};
    Map<String, List<String>> map = Stream.of(array)
            .filter(item -> item.contains(","))
            .map(item -> item.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    item -> item[1],
                    Collectors.mapping(item -> item[0], Collectors.toList()))
            );
    System.out.println(map);
```

Output will be: `{group2=[form4], group1=[form1, form2, form3]}`

Comment: That seems pretty close to what I was thinking, but should the map be:  .map(item -> item.toString().split(",")) ?

Comment: Which output you expect?

Comment: Ideally the same I am already getting so: A list (or map in this case) where I can just check if the current product's form exists in the List<String> then set that product form to that entrySet's key instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be good for a Map. You could have a Map containing a String as the key, and a List as the values.The key being the group, and the value could be a list of strings, that would be forms. Maybe something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> string = new HashMap<>();
```